# Not getting JSON object. AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, post, controller

I am new in Angular and trying to **POST** data , but I am getting undefined status. My **JSON** raw body is like this :

```
{
    "Name": "Something",
    "Description": "Something",
    "Data": []
}
```

Name and description is from user input field and Data will be used later to push another JSON object in the array.

I tried but not getting exact output.

**Controller:-**

```
app.controller('postController', ['$scope', '$http', 'appService', function ($scope, $http, AppService) {

    $scope.addInfos = [{
        Name: $scope.name,
        Description: $scope.description,
        Data: []
    }];
    $scope.Create = function () {
        $scope.addInfos.push({
            'Name': $scope.Name,
            'description': $scope.Description,
            'Data': []
        });
        $scope.dataObj = {
            Name: $scope.name,
            Description: $scope.description,
            Data: []
        };
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://192.120.27.8:2000/api/Add',
            data: $scope.dataObj
        }).then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("success");
            console.log(data + $scope.Name + $scope.Description);
        }, function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("error");
        });

        $scope.name = '';
        $scope.Description = '';

    };
```

**HTML page :-**

```
<div class="input-group  col-md-10">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="reg_input" >Name</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" ng-model="addInfos.name">
</div>

<div class="input-group sepH_b col-md-10">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="reg_input" >Description</span>
    <textarea name="reg_textarea" id="reg_textarea" cols="10" rows="3" class="form-control" ng-model="addInfos.description"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <a style="" class="btn btn-md btn-primary" ng-click="Create(addInfos)">Create</a>
</div>
```

The output which I can see in my console is `[object Object]`. What mistake am I doing here ?
***NOTE:-*** Here I didn't mentioned **Data:** field as it will be predefined array as of now like this `{data:[]}` need to inject and pass Name and Description in JSON as I mentioned above.

SECOND also I need to push this over all output data to the **Service** to store for further use.

Comment: it should be `.then(function (data)` or `.success(function (data, status, headers, config)` (`.then` will have a nested object, so use `data.data`)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Thanks I can get the one of the info for successful POST . But this is not the solution I exactly want . My Name , Description and Segment are not getting injected in the object. As the data is being populated without these infos.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys , now I can able push necessary datas inside the JSON I did second work around .

```
$scope.addInfos = {Data: []};

     $scope.Create = function() {
     $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : 'http://192.120.27.8:2000/api/Add',
            data : $scope.addInfos
             }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) { 
                  growl.success("Created a new File");  
                   console.log(data);
                  },function (data, status, headers, config) { 
                       growl.error("Something is wrong");
                  });

     };
```

My second concern is still there , now how to push these data to a service. `var something =[];`?